# How Can Conflict Between Mouse Events Be Resolved

Tags: javascript

I have a div called starter-box that when clicked is supposed to dynamically create 2 divs. I added an event listener to the parent of the starter-box div to listen for any event of the 2 dynamically created divs.

The problem is that the click event listener conflicts with the mousedown event listener preventing it (the click event) from executing.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var container = document.querySelector("#container");
  var target;
  var elementCreated = false;
  var elements = [];

  container.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
    target = ev.target;
    if (target.className != "box" && target.id != "container") {

      if (elementCreated == false) {
        createElements(target);
      } else if (elementCreated == true) {
        removeElementsByClass("box");
        elements = [];
      }  
    }
  });

  container.addEventListener("mousedown", (ev) => {
    target = ev.target;
    alert("MouseDown on: " + target.id);
  });

  container.addEventListener("mouseup", (ev) => {
    target = ev.target;
    alert("MouseUp on: " + target.id);
  });

  function createElements(target) {
    const dimensions = target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const element1 = document.createElement('div');
    element1.className = "box";
    element1.id = "box1";
    element1.style.left = (dimensions.left) + "px";
    element1.style.top = dimensions.bottom + 25 + "px";
    container.appendChild(element1);

    const element2 = document.createElement('div');
    element2.className = "box";
    element2.id = "box2";
    element2.style.left = (dimensions.left) + "px";
    element2.style.top = dimensions.bottom + 90 + "px";
    container.appendChild(element2);
  }
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: blue
}
#starter-box {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="starter-box">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not your listeners are the problem, your alerts are.

Comment: Please add the relevant code, in the form of a *runnable* snippet to the question body, so that it remains relevant for future users having the same problem even after the external link is no longer available.

Comment: change `alert` with `console.log` and you will the code works as expected...

Answer (score 1):

Check the fields of event object (ev argument to the listener callback).

- In case of 'click' event:   ev.type === 'click'
- In case of 'mousedown' event:    ev.type === 'mousedown'

You can use it your logic.

Discover the event object, try to console.log(ev), and see. There are more differences.

Comment: It appears https://stackoverflow.com/users/1080064/tkausl is correct, the issue stems from the use of alert in the callback of my addEventListener and using console.log will resolve this issue. The question I have now is what if I would like to use alert instead of console.log, how can I make that work.

Comment: @gapi I see you use global variable target, which most likely becomes undefined in some point, hence will not appear at alert.   
Better, define a local variable at the listener callbacks, i.e. move line "var target" to each listener rather than define it once at the beginning. So you will avoid overriding/erasing it by each callback. 

Additional suggestion: even you wish to use alert, or another UI element to display the data - as the first step debug it with console.log.